# Why does GCC remove the whitespace between the preprocessing tokens?

Tags: c, gcc, token, language-lawyer, c-preprocessor

Sample code:

```
#define X(x,y)  x y
#define STR_(x) #x
#define STR(x)  STR_(x)
STR(X(Y,Y))
```

Invocations:

```
$ gcc t222.c -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -E -P
"Y Y"

$ gcc t222.c -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -E -P -D"Y()"
"YY"
```

Why does GCC remove the whitespace between the preprocessing tokens?

For example, clang doesn't:

```
$ clang t222.c -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -E -P -D"Y()"
"Y Y"
```

UPD1. Somehow gcc takes into account the whitespace between `,` and `Y`:

```
$ gcc t222.c -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -E -P -D"Y()" -D"Z=STR(X(Y,Y))"
"YY"

$ gcc t222.c -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -E -P -D"Y()" -D"Z=STR(X(Y, Y))"
"Y Y"
```

UPD2. This:

```
STR(X(Y,
Y))
```

leads to:

```
$ gcc t222.c -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -E -P -D"Y()"
"Y Y"
```

However, this:

```
STR(X(Y
,Y))
```

leads to:

```
$ gcc t222.c -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -E -P -D"Y()"
"YY"
```

UPD3. Reported: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=104147.

Comment: I don't quite dare yell "bug" yet, but it would seem that gcc is non-conforming as per C17 6.10.3.2 "Each occurrence of white space between the argument’s preprocessing tokens becomes a single space character in the character string literal."

Comment: @user694733 — no; it is only an invocation of the function-like macro if the token after the macro name is an open parenthesis.  That is crucial.  It allows you to override a macro definition of a function by surrounding the identifier in parentheses: `int u = (toupper)(c);` must invoke the function `toupper()` even if there is a function-like macro.  The introduction to the library section of the standard explicitly calls this out.

Comment: Btw adding `#define Y()` on top of the sample code gives the same result so it isn't related to the `-D` option.

Comment: @user694733 As I understand `Y` is not an invocation of the function-like macro, because there is no `(` following the `Y` (after zero or more white spaces).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bug in GCC. C 2018 6.10.3.2 specifies behavior of the `#` operator. Paragraph 1 says “Each `#` preprocessing token in the replacement list for a function-like macro shall be followed by a parameter as the next preprocessing token in the replacement list.” We see this in the `#x` of `#define STR_(x) #x`.

Paragraph 2 says:

> If, in the replacement list, a parameter is immediately preceded by a `#` preprocessing token, both are replaced by a single character string literal preprocessing token that contains the spelling of the preprocessing token sequence for the corresponding argument. Each occurrence of white space between the argument’s preprocessing tokens becomes a single space character in the character string literal. White space before the first preprocessing token and after the last preprocessing token composing the argument is deleted…

The `X(Y,Y)` macro invocation must have resulted in the tokens `Y` and `Y`, and we see in `#define X(x,y)  x y` that they would have white space between them.

White-space in a macro replacement list is significant, per 6.10.3 1, which says:

> Two replacement lists are identical if and only if the preprocessing tokens in both have the same number, ordering, spelling, and white-space separation, where all white-space separations are considered identical.

Thus, in `#define X(x,y)  x y`, the replacement list should not be considered to be just the two tokens `x` and `y`, with white space disregarded. The replacement list is `x`, white space, and `y`.

Further, when the macro is replaced, it is replaced by the replacement list (and hence includes white space), not merely by the tokens in the replacement list, per 6.10.3 10:

> … Each subsequent instance of the function-like macro name followed by a `(` as the next preprocessing token introduces the sequence of preprocessing tokens that is replaced by the replacement list in the definition (an invocation of the macro)… Within the sequence of preprocessing tokens making up an invocation of a function-like macro, new-line is considered a normal white-space character.

Comment: That a replacement list can include whitespace is also supported by paragraph 7 "Any white-space characters preceding or following the replacement list of preprocessing tokens are not considered part of the replacement list for either form of macro."

Comment: Found this in Bugzilla: [Bug 31869 - stringifying empty macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=31869). Seems to be the same bug and they claim that it was fixed.